# Send form from AngularJS to Symfony

Tags: angularjs, symfony

I want to send data from an Angular form to a Symfony controller and
insert the information about a client into a database.

This is my markup:

```
<form ng-submit="submit()" ng-controller="Add" name="theForm">
    nom : <input name="nom" ng-model="nom"><br>
    prenon: <input name="prenom" ng-model="prenom"><br>
    Nom d'utilisateur <input name="username"ng-model="username"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="ajouter" name="ajouter" ><br>
</form>
```

This my controller :

```
$scope.submit = function() {
    $http.post('/someplace', $scope.theForm);
}
```

But I don't know how to recover the data in my Symfony controller and then insert it into a database. How can I do that with my current setup?

Comment: i want to now how recovered the data in a controller symfony and how insert the information into a database

Comment: I tried to put your comment back into the question, but it's still not very clear what exactly you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You want to first define a Symfony Service for your Angular controller to communicate with. This will be the location '/someplace' and you will be sending the data in $scope.theForm.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/service.html

Once you have developed the connection to this service from the form, you need to ensure your database connection is configured and registered.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/pdo_session_storage.html

The overall question you ask is incredibly broad, but hopefully these couple links will get you started in the right direction(s).

Comment: And thank you but these couple links didn't help me 
i have a web service i instaler the FOSRestBundle
i know how to send response with json but i want now to know how recive the information send bye formulaire angular in my controller symfony

Comment: Go through the following 'Recipe' and hook up to a database via the Doctrine DBAL { http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/dbal.html }

Comment: soory but you have not understood my issue!
I have a Formulaire crated on angularjs ok ?

this is my controller js 
$scope.submit = function() {
    $http.post('/someplace', $scope.theForm);
}
i don't now is it correct or no 
and now i want to recive the infomation send with angular in a controller symfony to insert it into database

Comment: your question is not clear. is it about getting data into a database OR viewing your data in the submit function? Maybe you should clarify the topic and be more specific. Ajouter votre commentaire en français et je vais le traduire.

Comment: ok j'ai un formulaire angularjs je veux envoyer les information (les donné saisir dans se formulaire ) ou controller pour qui'il insérer ses information dans la base de donné ! 
c a dire je vous ajouter par exemple un client dans la base de donne 
le client sais ses information dans une  formulaire crée en angularjs 
l'angular envoyer les information au controler symfony pour qu'il insert ses information dans la base ? est ce que c claire ?

Comment: alors mon question est comme faire pour envoyer les information saisir dans le formulaire angularjs ou controller symfony et ensuite comment je récupéré les informations qui son't envoyer par le formulaire angularjs dans le controller symfony pour les inséré dans la base de donné est ce que c claire ?

Comment: Je suis désolé, mais vous posez une question aussi vaste qu'il ya trop de réponses et tous sont très long. Les liens que je ai envoyé vous répondre à votre question, mais vous aurez à mettre en avant l'effort.

Comment: Désolé mais je pense que vous n'avez pas comprend mon question 
j'ai utlise le framework symfony et angularjs pour réaliser mon application j'ai instaler le FOSRestBundle pour crée le web service 
donc je vous faire un formulaire créé en angular et qu'il envoyer les données ou controller symfony pour qu'il insert ses données dans la base si simple mais je sais pas comme faire je vous quelque exemple pour comprend

Comment: Do not rush when creating your question. It is obvious that you have little experience with this and you need to ask smaller questions. -- Ne vous précipitez pas lors de la création de votre question. Il est évident que vous avez peu d'expérience avec cela et vous devez demander petites questions.

Answer (score 0):

Well actually you first want to define a route and a controller. 
So in you routing.yml file add a route something like

```
ajax_post_route_name:
    path:     /someplace
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeDemoBundle:Main:someplace }
```

The create the actual controller in the given route, and the action with the name. In this example you should create a file something like this:

```
// src/AcmeDemoBundle/Controller/MainController.php
<?php

namespace AcmeDemoBundle/Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controllerș

class MainController extends Controller
{

    public function someplaceAction(Request $request)
    {
         //Your logic here
         $data = $request->all();
         $form = new Form();
         $form->bind($request);
         //... 
    }
}
```

Maybe these links are more relevant:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/controller.html